# How to react on newly created Appointments?

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server, ewsjavaapi

I am looking for a way to get a delta of Appointments. Basically what I want is to react on newly created Appointments.

To get newly created / unread messages there is a `SearchFilter` in the `java ews api` that I use. Unfortunately `AppointmentSchema` does not provide any fitting Enum for the filter.

```
new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
```

I get the Appointments like:

```
    CalendarFolder calendarFolder = CalendarFolder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
    var result = calendarFolder.findAppointments(cView);
```

so back to my question. How can I notice if someone invited me to a new Appointment or an email with a new Appointment invitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution, luckily. `MeetingRequest` is the `Item` I am looking for.

```
FindItemsResults<Item> result = service.findItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(getCredentials())), getUnreadEmailFilter(), new ItemView(10));
result.forEach(n -> {
    if (n instanceof MeetingRequest) {
       System.out.println("New Appointment - MeetingRequest found!");
       MeetingRequest req = (MeetingRequest) n;
       req.accept(true);
    }
}
```